# Is the rank of this elliptic curve positive?

Tags: elliptic-curves

For every rational number $h$, does there exist a rational $t$ such that the rank of the elliptic curve $$Y^2=X^3 -3h^2t^8X -(h^4t^{16}+h^2t^8),$$ is positive?

Comment: I would appreciate any answers to this question. Is it right? It seems right, but how I can prove it?

Comment: How does this problem arise in your work?

Comment: We use this elliptic curve in  elliptic curves cryptosystems.(Ecc)

Comment: There might be a cheap trick for doing this -- but on the other hand it could well be the case that giving an unconditional proof of this might be hard or even open. Sometimes you can do tricks involving showing that two distinct values of $t$ give two elliptic curves with different global signs in the functional equation and then you're done if you believe BSD, but perhaps you should make clear whether an answer which depends on standard conjectures is suitable from your point of view. You've asked lots of questions about these curves recently but the arithmetic of ell curves can be hard.

Comment: In the above problem, I mean, If h is an arbitrary fixed rational number, does there exist any  rational t such that the rank of the elliptic curve is positive?Is this right for every h?I maen ,for every h given, exist t such that rank is positive?

Comment: I know what you mean. What I am saying is that the result might be true but it might be hard to prove it, because we can't prove the Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture so *maybe* the only viable method we have for proving the rank is positive is to explicitly write down a point of infinite order -- but Diophantine equations are notoriously hard to solve. Are you prepared to accept that the answer might be "this might be true but perhaps nobody can prove it"? On the other hand maybe you'll be lucky and someone will come up with something cheap.

Comment: Here are some people (including some experts) wondering whether something slightly more general is a reasonable conjecture: http://mathoverflow.net/a/63970/1384 .

Comment: Dear Prof Kevin Buzzard; Thank you very much for your explaning and your guide. Yes. I understand what you mean about this problem. But I think, perehaps it to be solved easily by some other tricks...

Comment: Dear professor Kevin Buzzard. Please guide me how I can get Denis Simon's  ellrank code for calculating the rank of elliptic curves with large coefficients? Are there any anline program for calculating the rank of elliptic curves with large coefficients? sincerely/

Comment: I am sorry that I have given wrong answer about the motivation of my
question regarding the EC that had 
posted on the website. As a matter
of fact I didn't give the appropriate 
answer to  secure our main problem 
of Diophantine equation.

Comment: I note that a positive answer to this question (in a slightly different form) is asserted, with no proof, in your arXiv paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02602 (second paragraph of page 4).

Comment: Thank you for your comments;You are right.This was the first version of my paper..we try to solve this problem in future....

Comment: You may see last version of our paper  in the raxiv next week,too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that one can expect an easy solution only if there are rational functions $X(h), Y(h), T(h)\in\mathbb Q(h)$ for a variable $h$ such that
$Y(h)^2=X(h)^3 -3h^2T(h)^8X(h) -(h^4T(h)^{16}+h^2T(h)^8)$.

I don't know how to decide easily if there are such functions. Still, the curve has an interesting feature: For $h=1$ it has positive rank over the rational function field $\mathbb Q(t)$, since $(X,Y)=(t^2+t^4+t^6,t^3+t^5+t^7+t^9)$ is a point on the curve, which is not torsion by Nagell-Lutz.

Comment: Dear Prof Peter Mueller. I appreciate your reply and your answer. thank you.. It is great. How did you find this answer? Please more explain about why this point is not torsion?

Comment: @mehdi: I was playing a little with the computer algebra system Sage, which can compute generators of the Mordell-Weil group of elliptic curves over the rationals. The point over $\mathbb Q(t)$ was found by polynomial interpolation of the various points over $\mathbb Q$. If the given point were a torsion point, then it would be one upon specializing $t$, for instance setting $t=2$. So $p=(84, 680)$ were a torsion point on $Y^2 = X^3 - 768X - 65792$, and so would be $3p$. However, $3p=(809236/729,-727724440/19683)$ has non-integral entries, contrary to Nagell-Lutz.